# Call multiple functions in elif statement python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input

I am trying to call multiple functions in a conditional but is impossible :/

Here is my code:

```
print("""
    1. Something 1
    2. Something 2
    3. Something 3 """)
    
user = input("Choose some option: ")

def one():
    print("Something...")

def two():
    print("Something 2...")

def three():
    print("Something 3...")

if user == 1:
    one()
elif user == 2:
    two()
elif user == 3:
    three()
```

But I don´t know when I choose some option (1-3) never print the function...

Comment: Please add the full traceback.

Comment: It's not clear what's your problem. Do you have an error?

Comment: You read strings, but compare against ints. `user = int(input("Choose some option: "))` to remedy.

Comment: Additionally, whenever you have multiple `if ... elif ... elif ...` blocks, always end with an `else` block to handle situations where none of the previous conditions are satisfied. Such as `else: print("input not recognized:", user)`. _(The only times it's okay to skip the final `else` is when (a) there's nothing to do with that situation and it's safe to continue or (b) you can guarantee that all the previous conditions have satisfied every possibility/potential values. And in the case of (b), your last `elif` should have been an `else`.)_

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where `domain_ip` comes from, but your current code doesn't work because the inputs are `str` and not `int`. Change the input line to

```
user = int(input("Choose some option: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string. You are checking against integers. That's why none of your conditions evaluates to true. Add a typeconversion before your if-block:

```py
user = int(input("Choose some option: "))
```

and validate the input, or just check against strings inside your if-logic.

Answer (score 0):

By default the input function parses what was given as a string.
You need to cast it as int.
If you change

```py
user = input("Choose some option: ") # user here is a string
```

To:

```py
user = int(input("Choose some option: ")) # now user is int
```

The code will work.